# How to properly specify condition: sum count = column value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

Im updating a system, trying to create a 'shadow' table of an orignal table, reciving changes through triggers, but not using the orginal table, since I really don't like the way the orignal program is designed.

One of them is a team configuration table, holding all the users & their team id. Users with the same team id are of the same team. I am trying to create trigger here to intercept data into a new team history log. (1 row / 1 team id)
But since after a team setup, multiple rows of the table get updated, and update is not done in batch, it's hard to tell when a new team setup is over. Fortunately there is this member_count column, which can be used to count the members and determine when all the nencessry records related to this new team_id are updated.

```
| team id     | uid | member_count |
|201701010800A| 1   | 3            |
|201701010800A| 2   | 3            |
|201701010800A| 3   | 3            |
```

My question is how should I specify this condtition in after-update trigger.
here is what I do for now. But it seems so hacky. I guess there are more sensible ways to express it.

```
if exists(
    select 1 from ( values (1) ) t(c) 
    outer apply (
        select count(team_id) tc, max(member_count) mx, min(member_count) mm
        from old_teamtable 
        where team_id = ( select top 1 team_id from inserted )
    ) e
    where tc = mx and mx = mm
)
```

Comment: Count(team) = member_count with a group by on member_count, and team_id should work?  Does the same thing, but seems simpler to me

Comment: yeah somehow, but the part I want to get rid of is `from ( value (1)) t(c) outer apply ` it feels kind of meaningless.

Comment: I don't really understand triggers at all, but unfortunately I find this question rather interesting... Could you explain exactly what output you need from this filter? Im figuring it's a true (bolean)    when count(Id) = member_count.  Does the one trigger handle both or one of new rows / updates?

Comment: That depends on how the data is submited, it could do mutiple `update set team_id=? where uid=?;` for each uid, or it can do `update set team_id=? where uid in (1,2,3)` for a update in batch. I am only using the `inserted`.team_id to locate the new team members, and determine when all members have new team_id set, so that I am sure I am not missing any memeber. The trigger could be called mutiple times, but only act when the timing is right. The `team_id` is a always unique id, which is another prerequisite for this to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code demonstrates one way to manage a team history table based on inserts to a teams and users table. The trigger fires after each `insert` to `TeamsAndUsers`. For new teams, not already in the `TeamHistory`, appropriate rows are added and marked `IsComplete = 0`. The `TeamHistory` is then updated by checking all the teams affected by the `insert` to see if they have the correct number of users. If so, the `IsComplete` bit is set to `1` for the corresponding rows in the `TeamHistory` table.

```
-- Create sample tables.
create table TeamsAndUsers ( Id Int Identity, TeamId Int, UserId Int, TeamMembers Int );

create table TeamHistory ( Id Int Identity, TeamId Int, IsComplete Bit );
go

-- Create the trigger.
create trigger UpdateTeamHistory
  on TeamsAndUsers
  after Insert
as
  set nocount on

  -- Handle any teams we've not heard of before.
  insert into TeamHistory ( TeamId, IsComplete )
    select distinct TeamId, 0
      from inserted
      where TeamId not in ( select TeamId from TeamHistory );

  -- See if any teams have been completed, i.e. all of their members are present.
  update TeamHistory
    set IsComplete = 1
    where TeamId in (
      select TAU.TeamId from (
        -- TeamId   values touched by the INSERT ...
        select distinct TeamId from inserted ) as i inner join
          -- ... matched with corresponding incomplete teams in the team history ...
          TeamHistory as TH on TH.TeamId = i.TeamId and TH.IsComplete = 0 inner join
          -- ... matched with users currently assigned to the teams.
          TeamsAndUsers as TAU on TAU.TeamId = i.TeamId
    group by TAU.TeamId
    having Count( TAU.UserId ) = Max( TAU.TeamMembers ) );
go

-- Test the trigger.
insert into TeamsAndUsers ( TeamId, UserId, TeamMembers ) values
  ( 101, 1, 3 ), ( 101, 2, 3 );
select * from TeamsAndUsers;
select * from TeamHistory;

insert into TeamsAndUsers ( TeamId, UserId, TeamMembers ) values
  ( 101, 3, 3 );
select * from TeamsAndUsers;
select * from TeamHistory;

insert into TeamsAndUsers ( TeamId, UserId, TeamMembers ) values
  ( 102, 4, 1 );
select * from TeamsAndUsers;
select * from TeamHistory;

insert into TeamsAndUsers ( TeamId, UserId, TeamMembers ) values
  ( 103, 10, 2 );
select * from TeamsAndUsers;
select * from TeamHistory;

insert into TeamsAndUsers ( TeamId, UserId, TeamMembers ) values
  ( 103, 11, 2 );
select * from TeamsAndUsers;
select * from TeamHistory;
```

Aside: The `select` in the `update` looks rather clumsy, but it's late here. It can probably be tidied up a little.

Comment: Thanks, I think the IsComplete part is a nice touch, though they are not useful for data report, the incomplete ones should be logged to spot malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
if exists (
    select  1 
    from    old_teamtable 
    where   team_id = (select top 1 team_id from inserted) 
    having  count(*) = max(member_count) 
    and     max(member_count) = min(member_count)
)
```